# Segmentation fault sending a vector on MPI

Tags: vector, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a 3d cube represented in a vector where it is divided vertically into faces between the MPI processes. In order to do the calculation I need to pass the face+1 and the face-1 to be able to compare the extremes. The problem comes when I make the sending and receiving that fails. I do not find the problem when the indices are correct.

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "aux.h"
#define STABILITY 1.0f / sqrt(3.0f)

void mdf_heat(double *u0,
              double *u1,
              double *aux,
              const unsigned int npX,
              const unsigned int npY,
              const unsigned int npZ,
              const double deltaH,
              const double deltaT,
              const double inErr,
              const double boundaries,
              const int me,
              const int np)
{
  double left, right, up, down, top, bottom;
  double alpha = deltaT / (deltaH * deltaH);
  MPI_Status status;
  int continued = 1;
  unsigned int steps = 0;

  while (continued)
  {
    steps++;
    if (me == 0)
    {
      MPI_Send(&u0[npX * npY * (npZ - 1)], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      // printf("(S:%d)(P:%d) Envio a %d\n", steps, me, me + 1);

      MPI_Recv(&aux[0], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      printf("(S:%d)(P:%d) Recibo de %d\n", steps, me, me + 1);
    }
    else if (me == np - 1)
    {
      MPI_Send(&u0[0], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      // printf("(S:%d)(P:%d) Envio a %d\n", steps, me, me - 1);

      MPI_Recv(&aux[0], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      printf("(S:%d)(P:%d) Recibo de %d\n", steps, me, me - 1);
    }
    else
    {
      MPI_Send(&u0[0], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&u0[npX * npY * (npZ - 1)], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      // printf("(S:%d)(P:%d) Envio a %d y %d\n", steps, me, me - 1, me + 1);

      MPI_Recv(&aux[0], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&aux[npX * npY], npX * npY, MPI_DOUBLE, me + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      printf("(S:%d)(P:%d) Recibo de %d y %d\n", steps, me, me - 1, me + 1);
    }

    ....

   }
   fprintf(stdout, "[%d] Done! in %u steps\n", me, steps);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{

  ....

  unsigned int npX = (unsigned int)(sizeX / deltaH);
  unsigned int npY = (unsigned int)(sizeY / deltaH);
  unsigned int npZ = (unsigned int)(sizeZ / deltaH) / np;

  u0_per_process = (double *)calloc(npZ * npY * npX, sizeof(double));
  u1_per_process = (double *)calloc(npZ * npY * npX, sizeof(double));

  if (me == 0 || me == np - 1)
    aux_per_process = (double *)calloc(npZ * npY * 1, sizeof(double));
  else
    aux_per_process = (double *)calloc(npZ * npY * 2, sizeof(double));

  printf("p(%d) (%u, %u, %u)\n", me, npX, npY, npZ);
  mdf_heat(u0_per_process, u1_per_process, aux_per_process, npX, npY, npZ, deltaH, deltaT, 1e-15, 100.0f, me, np);

  ....

}
```

Console error:

```
mpirun ./a.out 0.125
p(1) (8, 8, 2)
p(3) (8, 8, 2)
p(2) (8, 8, 2)
p(0) (8, 8, 2)
(S:1)(P:3) Recibo de 2
(S:1)(P:0) Recibo de 1
(S:1)(P:2) Recibo de 1 y 3
(S:1)(P:1) Recibo de 0 y 2
[mateev:113552] *** Process received signal ***
[mateev:113549] *** Process received signal ***
[mateev:113549] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[mateev:113549] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[mateev:113549] Failing at address: 0x48
[mateev:113550] *** Process received signal ***
[mateev:113550] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[mateev:113550] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[mateev:113550] Failing at address: 0x48
[mateev:113552] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[mateev:113552] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[mateev:113552] Failing at address: 0x48
a.out: malloc.c:4036: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb)' failed.
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
[mateev:113552] *** Process received signal ***
[mateev:113552] Signal: Aborted (6)
[mateev:113552] Signal code:  (-6)
[mateev:113550] *** Process received signal ***
[mateev:113550] Signal: Aborted (6)
[mateev:113550] Signal code:  (-6)
[mateev:113549] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x430c0)[0x7f8bb12180c0]
[mateev:113549] [ 1] /home/vladimir/.openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_send+0x77)[0x7f8bb0177417]
[mateev:113549] [ 2] /home/vladimir/.openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40(PMPI_Send+0x123)[0x7f8bb1488fb3]
[mateev:113549] [ 3] ./a.out(+0x1419)[0x55899d429419]
[mateev:113549] [ 4] ./a.out(+0x1965)[0x55899d429965]
[mateev:113549] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f8bb11f90b3]
[mateev:113549] [ 6] ./a.out(+0x128e)[0x55899d42928e]
[mateev:113549] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node mateev exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried to play with the indexes, if I only send 1 double it doesn't have the segmentation fault.
But cannot send the entire face.

Comment: I guess this is a buffer overflow. You can catch the location of such error easily using debugger like gdb. Because you use MPI, you need to attach gdb to the the process. You also need to build your program with debugging information (ie. the flag `-g`). Such method will not only certainly help you to track why this problem appears, but also help you to solve many future problems like this one. You can also use Valgrind to track the malloc associated to the buffer overflow.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Im compiling with the -g flag and using ARM Forge for debugging... the error seems to be on the sends but cannot understant...

Comment: first you should always check `calloc(...)` does not return `NULL`. Then you receive `npX*npY` elements but you allocated `npZ*npY`.